# Why are some "updated app" dots brighter?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, springboard

Since updating to iOS 10, when I update my apps, some of the indicator dots are bright cyan instead of blue. For example, Deltek in the screenshot (compared to Sheets). Why?

**edit:** In response to IconDaemon's comment, first, the light color was constant as I swiped to and from the page, with the background stationary. Second, I just checked again, and it's now the normal dark blue (see below). I didn't change the background or transparency settings. It might just be a bug, but I don't think it's an illusion or background interaction.

**edit 2:** I just updated Facebook Messenger and it happened again. The dot is bright cyan, regardless of its position against the background. Then after I use the phone for a few minutes, it changes to the normal color. 3 images showing the bright color, followed by the dark color: https://i.stack.imgur.com/elYeA.jpg

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

Comment: It is because the colors in the background behind the dots tricks your brain into seeing another colored dot. That's all. See [this reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios9/comments/3q7a9y/what_do_different_color_blue_dots_next_to_app/) for some visual verification.

Comment: @IconDaemon, I don't think it's an illusion or background interaction. See my edit.

Comment: Perhaps the [ambient light sensor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202613) is affecting the color reproduction of the screen based on the changing light-levels illumination in your location, thus causing the colors of the dots to change because of the background?

Comment: It's been sitting in basically the same place in the same light, and I don't think brightness adjustments due to the ambient light sensor would affect screenshots.

Comment: Based on your comments about it changing after a period of time, my best guess is that the lighter shade represents apps updated within the last few minutes, and the darker shade is apps before that period.

Comment: @tubedogg It turns out not to be that simple; I've now seen the same dots switch from bright to dark to bright multiple times at seemingly random intervals

Comment: To see how the background affects the dot color, move the app icon around on the home screen. Tested on iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed some of the dots on mine were a lighter color several hours after an update was downloaded, which would blow my theory about timing, so I tested changing wallpapers to see how that affected the color. This showed that the color of the dot is impacted by the wallpaper. It may be semi-transparent or the color may simply be chosen by the system based on the color behind it.

The below images were taken within a minute of each other after changing the wallpaper. The first two show changing from a light wallpaper to a dark one. The second, third, and fourth images were all taken with the same wallpaper. You can see the color darkens as the background darkens. In the fourth image, it even varies slightly between rows based on the differing shades in the background.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe that has something to do with background brightness.or may be the dot has attribute like opacity.

Comment: Here's the effect occurring against a completely pure black background: https://imgur.com/a/DJuYn

Comment: (I can believe the intent is for it to be a background-related effect, but it seems really buggy and inconsistent for me.)